# Laravel & Mockery: Unit testing the update method without hitting the database

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

Alright so I'm pretty new to both unit testing, mockery and laravel. I'm trying to unit test my resource controller, but I'm stuck at the update function. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or just thinking wrong.

Here's my controller:

```
class BooksController extends \BaseController {

    // Change template.
    protected $books;

    public function __construct(Book $books)
    {
        $this->books = $books;
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created book in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $data       = Input::except(array('_token'));
        $validator  = Validator::make($data, Book::$rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::route('books.create')
                ->withErrors($validator->errors())
                ->withInput();
        }

        $this->books->create($data);

        return Redirect::route('books.index');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified book in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $book       = $this->books->findOrFail($id);
        $data       = Input::except(array('_token', '_method'));
        $validator = Validator::make($data, Book::$rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            // Change template.
            return Redirect::route('books.edit', $id)->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        }

        $book->update($data);

        return Redirect::route('books.show', $id);
    }
}
```

And here are my tests:

```
public function testStore()
{
    // Add title to Input to pass validation.
    Input::replace(array('title' => 'asd', 'content' => ''));

    // Use the mock object to avoid database hitting.
    $this->mock
        ->shouldReceive('create')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn('truthy');

    // Pass along input to the store function.
    $this->action('POST', 'books.store', null, Input::all());

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('books');
}

public function testUpdate()
{
    Input::replace(array('title' => 'Test', 'content' => 'new content'));

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->once()->andReturn(new Book());
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('update')->once()->andReturn('truthy');

    $this->action('PUT', 'books.update', 1, Input::all());      

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('books/1');
}
```

The issue is, when I do it like this, I get `Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method update() from Mockery_0_Book should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.` because of the `$book->update($data)` in my controller. If I were to change it to `$this->books->update($data)`, it would be mocked properly and the database wouldn't be touched, but it would update all my records when using the function from frontend.

I guess I simply just want to know how to mock the `$book-object properly`.

Am I clear enough? Let me know otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: At first I thought your `$this->book` was a [repository](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/) but looking closer it looks more like it's just an Eloquent model. Is that the correct?

Comment: Correct. I thought about using repositories but figured it would cause too much confusion for me at this point.

Comment: The problem is that this is one of the major reasons people use repositories: it makes testing so much easier.

Comment: But there's gotta be a way to mock the single $book object right? Am I really forced to use the repository pattern in order to unit test the entire controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mocking out the `findOrFail` method not to return a `new Book`, but to return a mock object instead that has an update method on it.

```
$mockBook = Mockery::mock('Book[update]');
$mockBook->shouldReceive('update')->once();
$this->mock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->once()->andReturn($mockBook);
```

Comment: You, good sir, are a lifesaver. That did the trick for me and it even makes sence. Thanks!

Comment: np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is a managed dependency and you use mock in your test it causes brittle tests.
Don't mock manage dependencies.

Manage dependencies: dependencies that you have full control over.